# Modelling C# Action in UML

Tags: c#, uml, action

I'm currently using my unorthodox UML skills to document some code.  Currently, I'm modelling a function that baffles me as far as UML is concerned.

In a nutshell, this function creates an `Action, and this`Action`runs a statemachine in either blocking or non-blocking fashion (i.e. calls either`Invoke`or`BeginInvoke`, respectively).

For example:

```
public void MyFunc()
{
    bool dummy_blocking;

    Action my_action = new Action( () => {
        RunSomeStateMachine();
    });

    if( dummy_blocking)
        my_action.BeginInvoke( null, null);
    else
        my_action.Invoke();
}
```

Would you just use a Create message to create an `Action`, and then in that `Action`'s lifeline call (to self) `RunSomeStateMachine`?  Following that, would you then use an alt fragment to either call `BeginInvoke` or `Invoke` on the `Action`?  The details around the `Action` are what really stump me.

EDIT -- here is an example of my first attempt:

[image]

Comment: a nice diagram would make that clearer ..http://www.websequencediagrams.com/

Comment: Yeah, I know I should have done that initially...  I just uploaded a diagram.  :)

Comment: Oh now i see why i was so confused, u are over-detailing a function call... I don't think that it's necessary at all, unless if for personal use to keep up with the internal working of your code, there is not much use for this in production - documentation

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't document code in that detail. IMHO, if someone wants to exactly know what a method is doing, he can just read this method.

Much more interesting to document is the higher context and how parts of the software play together. Who is triggering this state machine, and what is it doing after all? Actions and stuff like this are just implementation details.

Comment: Fair enough!  I'll use that viewpoint and see what comes out of it.